# Как отлаживать написанное приложение средствами Android SDK?

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, eclipse

Здравствуйте. Пишу простенькие примеры в Eclipse под Android. Самое распространенное событие по их запуску на эмуляторе устройства - неожиданное их завершение системой Android с выводом стандартного сообщения. На тематических форумах (а так же добрые люди на ХэшКоде) советуют изучать логи инструмента LogCat, DDMS и т.д. 
Но, проблема в том, что я никак не осознаю что и как там следует отслеживать. В литературе об этом ничего не сказано, кроме того, что такие инструменты есть и они удобные. 
Однако, как люди выходят на строки в коде, вызывающие исключение, какие-то логические ошибки (вроде тех, что вызывают переполнение массива и т.д.)?
Умоляю тех, кто работает под Eclipse с Android SDK, напишите хоть какие-то инструкции или дайте ссылки на непосредственно тему отлавливания ошибок и исключений в приложении, т.е. на дебаг приложения построчно.

Answer (score 6):

Когда вы открываете DDMS он умеет писать обо всем, что происходит на телефоне/эмуляторе.
Когда происходит критическая ошибка, которую автор приложения не удосужился отловить, Android сам нарисует вам трассировку ошибки от и до.

Если же вы хотите сами все отслеживать, тогда воспользуйтесь классом Log, который имеет ряд функций, для вывода различных сообщений (например, i - info, w - warning, e - error). В DDMS они различаются цветом, для самого Андроида, вероятно еще чем-то, в эти подробности не лез.

Не забывайте использовать try...catch и отлавливать исключительные ситуации, затем их так же можно вывести в лог, используя Log класс.

И более того, DDMS умеет отслеживать потоки, кучу, имеет собственный файл-эксплорер. Все это на вкладках. И еще множество других фич, которые стоит просто попробовать.

**UPD**

Простейший код:

```
try {
        int p = Integer.parseInt("7.5");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        for(StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : e.getStackTrace())
            Log.e("StackTrace", stackTraceElement.toString());
    }
```

Получаем следующее в DDMS:

[image: ddms]

Comment: 2Dex
"Android сам нарисует вам трассировку ошибки от и до."
Т.е. он отошлет меня в конкретную строку в методе моего класса? Как настроить на такой режим работы DDMS? У меня ничего подобонго не наблюдается, просто поток красных строчек в консоли LogCat с малопонятными предупреждениями и ошибками.
Нет ли какого-то конкретного примера или ситуации с пояснениями?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Во-первых, если у вас не включена перспектива DDMS в Eclipse, тогда включите ее: Window -> Show Perspective -> DDMS (данная перспектива уже включает в себя LogCat). Во-вторых, запустите эмулятор, когда он запустится, слева вверху перспективы, вы увидите вкладку "Devices", и список устройств, одно из них (ваш эмулятор) нужно выбрать щелчком, после чего вы увидите сообщения в LogCat и сможете работать с вкладками "Threads", "Heap", "Emulator Control". В LogCat вы получаете все системные сообщения от эмулятора, включая то, что выдаете в программе через Log.w|i|e...

Comment: И да, красным цветом будет подсвечена ошибка. В UPD к ответу проиллюстрирую.

Comment: Спасибо. Более-менее прояснил для себя принцип работы DDMS.
С горем пополам отследил у себя исключение в работе метода setViewValue, переопределенного интерфейса ViewBinder, который я назначал своему переопределенному SimpleCursorAdapter.
В итоге, нашёл свою ошибку - не тот компонент разметки задействовался в методе setViewValue.